# How can I split a string with multiple amount of delimiter powershell?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, split

I've been trying to solve my problem for a while,

I got a name stored as a string which looks like this.

```
FirstName LastName d111
```

I'd like to store FirstName LastName as a variable

I tried using the code `$Name.Split("d11")[0]` which worked for a while until I realised if the name contains "d" it is acting like a delimiter too.

Could anyone help me solving this problem?

Thank you guys

Comment: Can you share a sample for which your condition doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always have a space and the fields in that order, you should be using the space as the delimiter:

```
$Name.Split(" ")[-4..-2] -join " "
```

This updated approach will go from the expected last item (-4) to the send to last item (-2).

-4 will work for you example, or something like this:

```
FirstName Middle Name LastName d111
```

If you want to be able to handle more fields, just tweak the number. e.g. -10 will handle up to 9 names, and leave out the last field (d111)

Comment: Would be a great idea but there are users who have 3 names, if nothing else helps I can use that in an if statement but I hope there is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help!

In the end I chose a harder solution than you mentioned, I might edit my code later.

The code I used if anyone needs it

```
        $user1 = $user.name.Split(" ")[0] #firstName
        $user1 = $user1 + " "
        $user2 = $user.name.Split(" ")[1] #secondName
        $user3 = $user.Name.Split(" ")[2] #thirdName

        if ($user3 -like "d111*")  
        { $user3 = $null
          $user = $user1 + $user2} 
        else 
        { $user2 = $user2 + " "
          $user = $user1 + $user2 + $user3}

$user1 =  $null
$user2 = $null
$user3 = $null
```